# How to ensure getting the most recent data from a tcp/ip socket?

Tags: c++, sockets, ubuntu, tcp, boost-asio

So I'm working with a camera which is connected to the computer by an ethernet cable and apparently, has to be accessed as a tcp/ip stream socket.

Basically, I want something like taking an image every 1 second. I noticed though that input data from the camera keeps coming in, while what I want is just to get the most recent data from the camera and nothing else, i.e. only the most current image at that time.

What I read so far is that I need to read the input data multiple times until I reach the 'most current data'. Is this really the only way to do this? I really don't like the idea of one process being busy all the time just to 'throw away' the incoming data from the stream socket.

Can't I, in theory, decrease the 'input buffer size' for the input from the socket so that I can receive only one picture's worth of data? And then, every further imcoming data would be just wasted, so when the input buffer is then flushed once, it gets filled with the newest data or something like that. (I mean, there has to be some limit on how much input data from the stream can 'pile up' waiting to be processed/read, right? What happens when that limit is reached? Does the further data gets thrown away or is the 'buffer' overwritten with the new data?)

Is that even possible? I'm a complete beginner at this, so I'm just theorizing. If something like that is possible, can anyone show the outline of how to code that? (I have to use the boost asio library on Ubuntu for this stuff)
That would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the only way to do it.

The whole reason for using TCP is that it is a "reliable" protocol, with guaranteed delivery. As opposed to UDP.

TCP's job is to deliver the data to the receiver, in the order it was sent, without losing anything. If the data cannot be delivered, the connection gets broken, at some point, when TCP gives up. But, as long as there's an active connection, the receiver is going to get everything that the sender sends.

If you don't want to get some data that the sender gets, you must make whatever appropriate arrangements there are, with the sender, for that to happen. TCP is not going to discard data, just because the receiver doesn't want it.

Comment: Hm, ok. Then, is it possible to use this UDP protocoll for an ethernet connection instead? Something like UDP/IP? (I only know that the camera device has a fixed IP and needs to be connected to with that)

Comment: You will have to consult the camera's technical reference manual. If the camera supports a UDP stream, well, you don't need my permission to use it.

Comment: I looked it up in the manual and it lists just 'tcp/ip stream' in the list of possible protocolls :-( Guess I'll then have to set up an extra thread for 'catching and throwing away' the incoming data in real time. Can't be helped, I guess.
Anyways, thanks for your help!